# Lightning Data Service Change Boolean

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am having trouble with LDS trying to load a page with fields tied to checkbox values. I am trying to display the boolean values as radio buttons and everything is loading correctly. However, the problem is whenever a radio button is changed I get the message 'Problem saving record, invalid data type' despite trying to return boolean values.
The basic functionality of LDS is working, however, since whenever I try to change the "Name" field on the record using just a "lightning:input" it works. Below is my code (I have cut out some code for brevity):

```
<aura:component>

<aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="caseRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[{'label': 'Yes', 'value':true},
                                                     {'label': 'No', 'value': false}]"/>



<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
  layoutType="FULL"
  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
  targetRecord="{!v.record}"
  targetFields="{!v.caseRecord}"
  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
  fields="Name, Id, fieldToChange__c"
  mode="EDIT"
  recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"
  />    
<lightning:radioGroup 
                      name="q14"    
                      aura:id="question14"    
                      label="change value"
                      options="{!v.options}"
                      value="{!v.caseRecord.fieldToChange__c  }"
                      type="radio"
                      />
     <lightning:button label="Save Account" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.handleSaveRecord}" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller (which is copied direct from Documentation):

```
 ({
    handleSaveRecord: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find("recordLoader").saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(saveResult) {

            // NOTE: If you want a specific behavior(an action or UI behavior) when this action is successful 
            // then handle that in a callback (generic logic when record is changed should be handled in recordUpdated event handler)
            if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
                // handle component related logic in event handler
            } else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.");
            } else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
                console.log('Problem saving record, error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            } else {
                console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + saveResult.state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            }
        }));
    },

    /**
     * Control the component behavior here when record is changed (via any component)
     */
    handleRecordUpdated: function(component, event, helper) {
        var eventParams = event.getParams();
        if(eventParams.changeType === "CHANGED") {
            // get the fields that changed for this record
            var changedFields = eventParams.changedFields;
            console.log('Fields that are changed: ' + JSON.stringify(changedFields));
            // record is changed, so refresh the component (or other component logic)
            var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            resultsToast.setParams({
                "title": "Saved",
                "message": "The record was updated."
            });
            resultsToast.fire();

        } else if(eventParams.changeType === "LOADED") {
            // record is loaded in the cache
        } else if(eventParams.changeType === "REMOVED") {
            // record is deleted and removed from the cache
        } else if(eventParams.changeType === "ERROR") {
            // there’s an error while loading, saving or deleting the record
        }
    }
})
```

Any help to why the radio buttons will not work would be greatly appreciated.  All of the other functionality is working as planned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified code of component and JS controller. This is working fine for me and saving value of radio button in field in database as well.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasSObjectName">

    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="caseRecord" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[{'label': 'Yes', 'value':true},
                                                        {'label': 'No', 'value': false}]"/>

    <aura:attribute name="value" type="String" default="option1"/>

    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetRecord="{!v.record}"
                      targetFields="{!v.caseRecord}"
                      targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                      fields="Name, Id, fieldToChange__c"
                      mode="EDIT"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"
                      />    
    <lightning:radioGroup 
                          name="q14"    
                          aura:id="question14"    
                          label="change value"
                          options="{!v.options}"
                          value="{! v.value }"
                          type="radio"
                          />
    <lightning:button label="Save Account" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.handleSaveRecord}" />
</aura:component>





({
    handleSaveRecord: function(component, event, helper) {
        var fieldValue = component.get("v.value");
        var record = component.get("v.caseRecord");
        if(fieldValue === 'true'){
            record.fieldToChange__c = true;
        }
        else{
            record.fieldToChange__c = false;
        }

        component.find("recordLoader").saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(saveResult) {

            // NOTE: If you want a specific behavior(an action or UI behavior) when this action is successful 
            // then handle that in a callback (generic logic when record is changed should be handled in recordUpdated event handler)
            if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
                // handle component related logic in event handler
            } else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.");
            } else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
                console.log('Problem saving record, error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            } else {
                console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + saveResult.state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            }
        }));
    },

    /**
     * Control the component behavior here when record is changed (via any component)
     */
    handleRecordUpdated: function(component, event, helper) {
        var eventParams = event.getParams();
        if(eventParams.changeType === "CHANGED") {
            // get the fields that changed for this record
            var changedFields = eventParams.changedFields;
            console.log('Fields that are changed: ' + JSON.stringify(changedFields));
            // record is changed, so refresh the component (or other component logic)
            var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            resultsToast.setParams({
                "title": "Saved",
                "message": "The record was updated."
            });
            resultsToast.fire();

        } else if(eventParams.changeType === "LOADED") {
            // record is loaded in the cache
        } else if(eventParams.changeType === "REMOVED") {
            // record is deleted and removed from the cache
        } else if(eventParams.changeType === "ERROR") {
            // there’s an error while loading, saving or deleting the record
        }
    }
})
```

ENJOY

Comment: Thank you, This worked for me, I didn't realize I would have to explicitly set the value to "true" or "false" in the controller.  I though Lightning data service would recognize the boolean by default